# How to deal with Property<T>, a change listener and initialization of the property?

Tags: java, properties, javafx, listener

I am using JavaFX's `Property<T>` class and I am quite happy with the result, minified example code:

```
public CircularListCursor<E> {
    private final Property<E> elementProperty;

    public CircularListCursor() {
        this.elementProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty(/*some value*/);
    }

    //various methods that call elementProperty.setValue(/*some value*/);
}
```

Usage:

```
private final CircularListCursor<SelectionData> selectionDataCursor;

...

selectionDataCursor.elementProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    oldValue.getLabel().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
    newValue.getLabel().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
});
```

Now this works *almost* perfectly, but it doesn't trigger on the construction of the object. It is logical that it works that way, because the property is not bound to yet during construction, so no change event can be fired either.

But I **do** want to be notified of the initial value during construction to allow for clean code, is there a way to do so?

Comment: So you're registering an internal `ChangeListener` at construction time (= in constructor of `CircularListCursor`)?

Comment: @isnot2bad No, the `ChangeListener` is being registered outside.

Comment: So you want it to get some kind of initial trigger when its registered (when `addListener` is called)?

Comment: @isnot2bad Correct, something like that was my idea

Comment: OK, got you. There is no support for that out of the box. We always use private methods as listeners directly (Java 8 method references), so we can call them at the end of construction once for initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct solution for that in JavaFX.

Nevertheless, you can make things a little bit easier/cleaner by moving the listener code into a private event handler method. This method can then be called once at the end of construction to initialize your object state. Thanks to Java 8 lambda expressions, you can use the method reference to the event handler method directly as listener:

```
// register event handler method    
selectionDataCursor.elementProperty().addListener(this::onElementChanged);

// call listener once for initialization:
onElementChanged(selectionDataCursor.elementProperty(), null, selectionDataCursor.getElement());

...

// event handler method
private void onElementChanged(ObservableValue<? extends E> observableValue, E oldValue, E newValue) {
    if (oldValue != null) oldValue.getLabel().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
    if (newValue != null) newValue.getLabel().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
}
```

---

Side note: Listeners built via method references can't be removed any more. More specific, the following code will NOT remove the listener, as `this::onElementChanged` will create a new listener every time that is not equal to the one that is already registered:

```
selectionDataCursor.elementProperty().removeListener(this::onElementChanged);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning method referenced listener removal. However if listeners are declared (even as method references) then they can be removed, e.g:
private ChangeListener exampleListener = this::onElementChanged;

Answer (score 1):

Using [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind), you can

1. Select the nested `styleProperty` from `elementProperty`.
2. Bind the nested `styleProperty` to some observable string (in your case, a constant string for red text fill).
3. Provide an additional string argument to the `bind` method that is used to reset the style property of the old element when the element changes.

Here is the code:

```
ObservableValue<String> constRed = new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-text-fill: red");
EasyBind.monadic(selectionDataCursor.elementProperty())
        .selectProperty(e -> e.getLabel().styleProperty())
        .bind(constRed, "-fx-text-fill: black");
```

Notice how you don't need to register any listeners—one binding does it all. A binding is more **declarative**, while a listener is more imperative (side-effectful).